# incrementing and decrementing shared variable at same time

Tags: deadlock

If x is initialized to 0 before any of this happens, what are the possible values of x after the following two for loops are executed concurrently in two different processes?  (One in each process)

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    x++

for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    x--
```

(edited)What can happen here?  Can any instructions fail, or will the result always be x = 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason why you should have a deadlock since there is no locking code. The different values of i and j depend on the non-deterministic order of thread execution.
Say the first thread starts, then stops by the time i=4, then the second thread starts, initializes i to zero and proceeds until the end of the first and second loop. The second thread resumes and exits immediately from the first loop as i=6 (value left by previous thread), then proceeds normally in the second loop.
This is but one scenario. You can come up with similar ones and the possibilities are endless.

Comment: i may have used the wrong word.  I should have asked what can go wrong here?

Comment: Too late, but this answer is wrong. There won't be any deadlocks of course, but the code contains a serious race condition. Plus the question is about the shared variable x, not i and j. Even if it was, the answer makes no sense.

Comment: @Beryram Gilfoyle I indeed mentioned the wrong variable. That said, loading x in a registry incrementing it is not atomic. So to threads manipulating the same variable without lock or other mechanism will get an inconsistent value in the variable.